# GNU Octave error "imfill: interactive mode not supported"

Tags: image, octave

I'm trying to use the `imfill` function from the Octave-Forge image package. I tried making a .m script and I also tried executing `imfill` function from the Octave GUI. Both times I get the same error:

> error: imfill: interactive usage is not yet supported

What is "interactive usage"? I thought interactive usage was when you use the interactive interpreter. I thought writing a script, making it executable, and running it from the CLI was more like "batch mode".

If "interactive usage" is not supported then what kind of usage is supported? How do I use `imfill`?

Below I have included the offending code.

```
fn   = args{1};                                                                                                                                              
I    = imread(fn);                                                                

Igray = rgb2gray(I);                                                           
Ibw   = im2bw(Igray);                                                          

se_2x2square = strel("square", 2);                                             

Iedge  = edge(uint8(Ibw));                                                     
Iedge2 = imdilate(Iedge, se_2x2square);                                        
Ifill  = imfill(Iedge2);
```

And here is the actual code from imfill that is throwing the error.

```
   if (islogical (img))
      ## imfill (BW)
      error ("imfill: interactive usage is not yet supported");
    else
      ## syntax: imfill (img)
      fill_holes = true;
    endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused by the term "interactive". The error is because I only gave `imfill` one argument. Currently calling imfill with only one argument (which I guess is interactive mode) is only implemented for grayscale images. Using a second parameter fixes the issue.

```
Ifill  = imfill(Iedge2, "holes");
```

, the arguments can be tweaked to get better results.

Comment: This is not a "poorly worded error". It clearly says that the way you call imfill (exactly one argument of binary type = `imfill (bw)`) is not yet implemented. Do you see that this usage is somewhere mentioned in the image [documentation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/function/imfill.html)? And of course feel free to provide a patch to provide the missing functionality

Comment: Hi @Andy. Maybe you're right. I just didn't understand what "interactive" meant. I was confused that imfill was only implemented for grayscale images and not black and white. I should have RTFM a little better,